# How to separate these dictionaries in this json ouput?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I tried to do a "with open .json" code, with multiple products info writing into it. However, in the .json file, each dictionary isn't separate each other with comma. Is it normal or did I code something wrong?

```
for product in data['prods']:
    product_name = product['name']
    prod_id = product['Id']
    prod_price = product['price']
    link = 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/' + prod_id
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    fileName = today + '_' + keyword + '_Pchome.json'
    try:
        with open(fileName, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
             json.dump({
                      "名稱":product_name,
                      "價格":prod_price,
                      "網址":link, 
             }, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, skipkeys=True)
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))
```

Edited: Changed my code to something like this(with more info since peopled are wondering.)

```
keyword = str(input('找什麼? '))
pages = 10
parse_word = urllib.parse.quote(keyword)
for page in list(range(1, pages)):
    response = requests.get('https://ecshweb.pchome.com.tw/search/v3.3/all/results?q=' + parse_word + '&page=' + str(page) + '&sort=rnk/dc')
    raw_data = response.content.decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    try:
        myData = []
        for product in data['prods']:
            product_name = product['name']
            prod_id = product['Id']
            prod_price = product['price']
            link = 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/' + prod_id
            myData.append({
                "名稱":product_name,
                "價格":prod_price,
                "網址":link
            })
            today = str(datetime.date.today())
            fileName = today + '_' + keyword + '_Pchome.json'
            try:
                with open(fileName, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    json.dump(myData, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, skipkeys=True)
            except Exception as err:
               print(str(err))
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))
print('完成!')
```

and my results becomes something down below..this time with double square bracket though...did I do something wrong

```
[
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS VivoBook Flip TP470EA-0112K1135G7 黑(i5-1135G7/8G/512G PCIe/Touch/Glare/W10/FHD/14)",
        "價格": 27900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFLY-A900BKJJV"
    }
][
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS VivoBook Flip TP470EA-0112K1135G7 黑(i5-1135G7/8G/512G PCIe/Touch/Glare/W10/FHD/14)",
        "價格": 27900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFLY-A900BKJJV"
    },
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS X515JF-0281G1035G1 星空灰(i5-1035G1/8G/MX130-2G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/15.6)",
        "價格": 23900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFL9-A900BLVZR"
    }
][
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS VivoBook Flip TP470EA-0112K1135G7 黑(i5-1135G7/8G/512G PCIe/Touch/Glare/W10/FHD/14)",
        "價格": 27900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFLY-A900BKJJV"
    },
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS X515JF-0281G1035G1 星空灰(i5-1035G1/8G/MX130-2G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/15.6)",
        "價格": 23900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFL9-A900BLVZR"
    },
    {
        "名稱": "ASUS X515MA-0471GN4120 星空灰(Celeron N4120/4G/256G PCIe/W10/FHD/15.6)",
        "價格": 14900,
        "網址": "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/DHAFM4-A900BL8H7"
    }
```

Here's an image of a sample from my json file.

[image: Sample from JSON file]

Comment: got a sample of your .json file? Also, `json.dump(<dict>)` will output a JSON string matching the contents of your `<dict>`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How does your data look like? What are you trying to separate?

Comment: edited the code, though it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not *wrong* per se, but certainly non-standard.  The typical pattern is to amalgamate everything you need into a single data structure, then `json.dump(...)` only *once*.  This way, you don't waste system IO resources opening the file again and again.  Then, you can simply load all the products at once with `json.load(...)`:

```py
product_data = []
for product in data["prods"]:
    product_name = product["name"]
    prod_id = product["Id"]
    prod_price = product["price"]
    link = "https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/" + prod_id
    product_data.append({"名稱": product_name, "價格": prod_price, "網址": link})
try:
    with open(fileName, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(product_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, skipkeys=True)
except Exception as err:
    print(str(err))
```

That being said, there are sometimes legitimate reasons you'd want to process different item (products in your case) independently, especially if gathering them is a long process and you want to achieve some sort of barebones fault tolerance if something goes wrong in the middle OR if there are so many products and you don't want to load all of them at once.  However, the problem with your approach is that you won't know *when* to stop reading the file to get each separate json object.  If you want to achieve something like this, simply write a newline (+ comma if you want to make it look like one valid json) after each iteration or take a look at [`jsonlines`](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead

Comment: had a edited version in the question, but now with other problem I guess :P

Comment: yes, same problem in your edited version of the question, you would still only want to initialize a my_pages and append each myData to that and then again just dump once OR manually write a comma + newline between each page (or use jsonlines)

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a string version of the data to the file, which causes the brackets to be next to each other without a comma. This would cause an error when trying to read from the file.

Instead, you should make your json file start off as a list, import the json file into your code, append your objects, then rewrite to the file.

You could do the following with some code similar to this:

```
myData = json.load(open(fileName))

for product in data['prods']:
  product_name = product['name']
  prod_id = product['Id']
  prod_price = product['price']
  link = 'https://24h.pchome.com.tw/prod/' + prod_id
  today = str(datetime.date.today())
  fileName = today + '_' + keyword + '_Pchome.json'
  myData.append({
    "名稱": product_name,
    "價格": prod_price,
    "網址": link,
  })

try:
  with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(myData, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, shipkeys=True)
except Exception as err:
  print(str(err))
```

As a temporary solution, if you want to fix the json file, you can put square brackets at the start and end of the file (assuming there are none) to turn it into an array. In addition, you can also add commas between each object in the array.

Comment: had a edited version in the question, but now with other problem I guess :P

Comment: @user15301225 The double brackets are occurring because of the `with open(fileName, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:`. This `a` means that it'll just add onto the file, instead of rewriting. In our case, we want to rewrite it since we already have the full JSON file loaded into Python. Therefore, you can just replace that line with `with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: no problem! If this solution fixed your problem, you can mark it as solved